# How to share and version protocol-buffers (proto) interface across projects and teams?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am working a series of Python project that involves making data available to other dev teams (C++/Python) via various services with gRPC. At the start of this initiative all files where self contained within the server project including the proto file. By the way, I version my project with https://semver.org/.

Then I started implementing a client/API library, as such I move the Proto file /generated code to the client project. I also made the server dependent on the client library using a Python package.

The server gets packaged in a RPM due to the nature of my environment (No Docker) while the client generates two artifacts 1) An RPM that can be statically linked for C++ projects, 2) A Pypi package that can be uploaded and downloaded via a Pypi repo. the server downloads the Pypi dependency via PIP.

The issue I have is that the SemVer on the client/API Library gives the wrong meaning as this ties both the version of the proto interface and the actual client version. This is an issue because if there is a bug in the client lib that forces a bump in the version number this will give the impresio that the proto interface has chnaged when this is untrue.

At this point, I am starting to think that I should have a third project that only contains the proto file and generated code. However, this is going to cause and an explosion of a small project (3x) in my git repo each time I need to implement a new service or purhaps I should group all my proto in a single project.

Would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to share proto files while keeping the semantics behind my version number ?

Answer (score 0):

Git submodule to manage common proto could solve your problem.

When you define a submodule you are sure that this portion of code is common to all the repo pointing to this module.

Also your submodule are in reality pointing to a commit. So if there are update on your module (proto model), you will have to pull manually the update into your buisness code.

On the other hand, if you are delivering a bug, if you don't update the submodule, you will not redeliver the proto.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this is a good idea if I own all the "client" repos however this could rapidly become a permission nightmare across different team repos.